# How to find the newest file of many in a set of folders?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I'm writing a batch file where I need to pick the newest of several import files that can be anywhere in a set of folders and copy it somewhere else for further processing. The directory tree looks like this:

- c:\import

  - c:\import\20190612
  - c:\import\20190613
  - c:\import\20190614
  - etc

Most days, but not every day, an import file lands into the folder structure above, in the folder with the corresponding date. The file is one of many, naming convention is [customerID]_[random number].xml, for example 94443_20152245.xml

I've tried using the FOR command:

```
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "c:\import\94443*.xml" /B /O:D') DO SET 94443=%%I
Copy "c:\import\%94443%" "c:\somewherelse\"
```

However, this only works for the top folder in the folder tree. I can't use the newest date and for example tell the command to look in c:\import\20190614, because I can't be certain that the folder tree received an import file for that customer at that date, I need to get the newest regardless of the date. Any suggestions?

Comment: What about this: `cd /D "C:\import" && for /F "delims= eol=|" %%J in ('dir /B /A:D /O:N "*"') do for /F "delims= eol=|" %%I in ('dir /B /A:-D /O:D "%%J\94443_*.xml"') do set "_94443=%%~fJ\%%I"`?

Comment: I tried this, and it did get me a file...but it was neither the oldest nor the newest one in the set.

Comment: I tried the switch /s in my own code, and it picked a file from the subfolders. Furthermore it picked the same file as your code, one with datestamp 29/3-2019. There are both newer and older files that matches in the same folder tree. Why does neither your code nor mine pick the newest file?

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"

:: Just an exercise - for customers 94440..94446 (there is no data for 94446)
FOR /l %%C IN (94440,1,94446) DO (

 SET "company_%%C="
 rem directories in reverse-order of name (= reverse-date-order) ONLY if files named "customer_something" exist
 FOR /f "delims=" %%d IN ('dir /ad /b /o-n "%sourcedir%"') DO IF EXIST "%sourcedir%\%%d\%%C_*" (
  rem list in reverse-date order (FOR TESTING PURPOSES ONLY, in NAME-ORDER)
  FOR /f "delims=" %%t IN ('dir /a-d /b /o-n "%sourcedir%\%%d\%%C_*"') DO IF NOT DEFINED company_%%C SET "company_%%C=%sourcedir%\%%d\%%t"
 )
 IF NOT DEFINED company_%%C SET "company_%%C=----Missing----"

)

:: display result
SET company_

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

For ease of testing, I simply applied different customer numbers to the main routine, examining a randomly-created tree of filenames.

Essentially, two steps - list the subdirectories in reverse-name order to `%%d`, then process each `%%d` in turn, but only if it contains data for the customer in question, assigning the first name found (`/on` is In NAME order FOR TESTING - you'd use reverse-date order, `/o-d`) and once the variable has been set, ignore further `set` attempts using `if not defined`

Then display the result...

Comment: That got me a bit further, however I have two new challenges: A) Sometimes the customerID have characters in them. Ie: NO94440 or SE94440. B) Not all subfolders are created according to date, some of them have other names: c:\import\22.06.2019, c:\import\21.06.2019,c:\import\testrun, c:\import\sftp and so forth. Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly:

```
set "srcDir=c:\import\"
set "destdir=c:\somewherelse\"
set "lastmod="

For /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`
  powershell -NoP -C "(Get-ChildItem -Path '%srcDir%' -Filter '94443*.xml' -File - 
Recurse | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).FullName"
`) Do Set "lastmod=%%a"

If defined lastmod (
   copy "%lastmod%" "%destDir%output.xml"
) else (
   Echo couldn't obtain  file
)
```